# What is this story I recall about an extremely long ever-changing character backstory?

Tags: history-of-gaming, product-identification, rpg-pop-culture

I read recently a post that was going around about a player who didn't like his DM, so he wrote an ever-changing backstory (hundreds of pages so no one would read it) for his character that allowed him to get out of just about every situation. The game went on for a year or two, I think.  I'm having trouble finding this retelling of the situation, which was by one of the other players (not the DM or the crafty player).  It might have been on reddit, I don't remember.  Does this ring a bell for anyone?  Can someone point me to it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57704/discussion-on-question-by-seanfromit-what-is-this-story-i-recall-about-an-extrem).

Comment: Y'all take it [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/are-questions-about-rpgs-on-topic), please.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You may be thinking of the story of [Old Man Henderson](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Old_Man_Henderson), the player who won Trail of Cthulhu. He had a 320 page backstory

The explanation of the backstory is as follows:

> The point to having such a long backstory was three-fold.
>
> 1: to ensure the GM would never actually read it and
>
> 2: Since he would never read it except for in excerpts I pointed out to justify things, I could re-write and change things around completely at random without anyone noticing and MOST IMPORTANTLY
>
> 3: Convince everyone that I was serious about this character, and that it wasn't simply the game wrecking bullshit that it was.

Comment: WARNING: If you click that link, you may not come back for a little while. Ye be Warned.

Comment: Totally forgot about this story, hours of my life are now gone again

Comment: Note that he actually just won *Trail of Cthulhu*, which runs off the much-more-forgiving Gumshoe system.

Comment: @fectin Good call. Such a distinction may seem trivial to outsiders visiting from the HNQ list, but that's actually a *really* important distinction. In the *Gumshoe* system, for instance, PCs start as *elite investigators* while the last time I played *Call of Cthulhu* the new PCs were about as useful as the Three Stooges. Underwater. On crack.